# UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed error when authenticating

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, auth0

Im using Auth0 for authenticating users for my react application.I have been trying to access resources on server side but I keep getting UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed as an Error.

I’ve followed a the following thread on the community forums: https://community.auth0.com/t/unauthorizederror-jwt-malformed-in-express-js/7352
Many users have suggested that the audience value from the guide is wrong. The audience given in the guide is  https:///userinfo but it should be ‘https://.auth0.com/api/v2/’, I’ve made that change and the error is still there.

This has worked for some people but not for me. 
This is the guide ive been following: https://auth0.com/blog/react-tutorial-building-and-securing-your-first-app/

```
const checkJwt = jwt({
  secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: `https://<domain>/.well-known/jwks.json`
  }),

  // Validate the audience and the issuer.
  audience: "https://<something>/api/v2/",
  issuer: `https://<something>/`,
  algorithms: ["RS256"]
});
```

this is the code ive written on the express side.

```
this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
      // the following three lines MUST be updated
      domain: "<Domain>",
      audience: "https://<Something>/api/v2/",
      clientID: "clientID",
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/callback",
      responseType: "token",
      scope: "openid"
    });
```

This is the code written on the frontend of the application.

Answer (score 2):

One of our senior engineers had a good recommendation on this that I will share below:

> If you haven't done so already you should perform these steps:
>
> 1. capture the token you receive; for example, using a console.log statement given this is in development.
> 2. review the captured token; does it look like a JWT?
> 3. if its a JWT and you can parse it at jwt.io then update the API to log the received token before trying to validate it; does the received
>      token match the one you expect?
>
> In conclusion, try to take steps that allow you to gather a bit more
>   of information.